# Need to print the values of a dictionary by calling the keys within a range

Tags: python, dictionary, exe

I made a dictionary with

```
key = integer   
value = string
```

I would like to make an .exe (probably it's a bit early for my level) where I can input 2 integers and it would print the values of the keys within the range I specified.

eg.

```
{1: 'General 001-002', 3: 'Computer science', 7: 'Bibliography', 20: 'Library & Information', 30: 'General 030-068', 69: 'Museum Science', 70: 'Journalism & News Media', 80: 'General 080-099', 100: 'Philosophy 100-149', 150: 'Psychology',}
```

I'd like to input 5 and 85 and want it to print

```
Bibliography  
Library & Information  
General 030-068  
Museum Science  
Journalism & News Media  
General 080-099
```

EDIT:

Thank you all for the suggestions.

My code looks like this right now and is working as it should:

```
text_file = open("dewey.txt", "rt")                     #Open the list containing the values

text = text_file.read().split('\n')
text_file.close()


num = []
with open ('dewey num.txt', 'rt') as in_file:           #Open the list containing the keys
    for line in in_file:
        num.append(line[:3])
intenum = []
for i in num:
    intenum.append(int(i))                              #Make the keys as integers


dict1= dict(zip(intenum,text))                          #Merge the 2 lists in a dictionary
print ('This software will give you the subjects for each stack.')                                  #Instructions for the user
print ('I need to know the range first, please only use the first three numbers of the classmark.') #Instructions for the user

x=input('Please key in the starting number for this stack: ')                                       #Input for start
y=input('Please key in the last number for this stack: ')                                           #Input for stop

start = int(x)
stop = int(y)

values = [dict1[k] for k in range(start, stop + 1) if k in dict1]                                   #Call the values in range
print('The subject(s) for this section: ')
for i in values:                                                                                    #Print the values in range
    print (i)
```

My next step is to make it an .exe so I'm studying py2exe, pyinstaller and cx_freeze. If you have any insight on what's better for my script it would be much appreciated.

I'm using Python 3.5.2

Alessio

Comment: this is not a "write me sofware" service, plese show us your code attempts.

Comment: If you know about the dictionary method `keys()` and the list method `sort()` (or builtin function `sorted()`), you should be able to work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is quite short:

```
# this is your dictionary
d = {1: 'General 001-002', 3: 'Computer science', 7: .....}

start = 5
stop = 85

values = [d[k] for k in range(start, stop + 1) if k in d]
```

You get what you need in `values` - a list.

I omitted most of the dictionary, but it's stored in `d`.

I used a list comprehension, taking the dictionary value at the key `k` for `k` running in the range (stop + 1 because `range` reaches to end of the range minus 1) provided that `k` is within the key values.

The expression

```
k in d
```

tests whether the key `k` is in the keys of the dict `d`, and it's the same as testing:

```
k in d.keys()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I never used a list comprehension, it's tidy!

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, once you taste the sweetness of Python there is no going back...  :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the key integers are much larger than the number of items in the dictionary it may be inefficient to loop over every integer in the range looking for keys that are present in the dictionary. An alternative strategy is to filter the keys of the dictionary, sort them, and then build a list of the desired values. Eg,

```
def key_range(d, lo, hi):
    r = range(lo, hi + 1)
    return [d[k] for k in sorted(k for k in d.keys() if k in r)] 

data = {
    1: 'General 001-002',
    3: 'Computer science',
    7: 'Bibliography',
    20: 'Library & Information',
    30: 'General 030-068',
    69: 'Museum Science',
    70: 'Journalism & News Media',
    80: 'General 080-099',
    100: 'Philosophy 100-149',
    150: 'Psychology',
}

# Test

for item in key_range(data, 5, 85):
    print(item)
```

**output**

```
Bibliography
Library & Information
General 030-068
Museum Science
Journalism & News Media
General 080-099
```

---

FWIW, here's a "functional" implementation of this algorithm.

```
def key_range(d, lo, hi):
    r = range(lo, hi + 1)
    return list(map(d.get, sorted(filter(lambda k: k in r, d.keys()))))
```

In Python 2, that `list` call can be eliminated, since the Python 2 version of `filter` returns a list. OTOH, in Python 2 the `k in r` test is rather inefficient; it would be *much* better to do `lo <= k <= hi`.